# Highcharts - Sunburst Module - series.data : Same var but one work, the other one not

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm struggling with a very strange problem using Highcharts Sunburst.
Before all, keep in mind that I've validate my JSON and test it in the JSFiddle demo (find in the documentation), everything works fine.

Here's my problem :

I get my data like that :

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('data_fap');
var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);
var chart_data = parsed_data.data;
```

( My JSON look like : `{data: [{id: "0", parent: "", name: " ", desc: " ", value: " "},...]}` )

If a used chart_data in the chart constructor, no chart, no error.

If I set my var this way :

```
var data = [{id: "0", parent: "", name: " ", desc: " ", value: " "},...]};
```

And use it in the chart constructor, everything works fine.

I was thinking it could come from my graph options so I copy/paste the one from JSFiddle, still not working...

Here's my complete chart generation code :

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('data_fap');
        var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);
        var new_data = parsed_data.data;

        // Splice in transparent for the center circle
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors.splice(0, 0, 'transparent');


        Highcharts.chart('graph_metier', {

            chart: {
                height: '100%'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Domaines et familles professionnels'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            series: [{
                type: "sunburst",
                data: new_data,
                allowDrillToNode: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '{point.name}',
                    filter: {
                        property: 'innerArcLength',
                        operator: '>',
                        value: 16
                    }
                },
                levels: [{
                    level: 1,
                    levelIsConstant: false,
                    levelSize: {
                        unit: 'percentage',
                        value: 30
                    }
                },{
                    level: 2,
                    colorByPoint: true
                },
                {
                    level: 3,
                    colorByPoint: true
                }]

            }],
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (event) {
                            if(event.point.parent != "0"){

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function(e){
                    if(e.chart.hoverPoint.options.id == 0){
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return '<b>' + e.chart.hoverPoint.options.name + '</b> (code: ' + e.chart.hoverPoint.options.id + ')<br>' + e.chart.hoverPoint.options.desc;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

If anyone could help me to understand this mess, I'll be infinitely grateful :)

Comment: Can you add the jsfiddle that isn't working?

Comment: Do you assign `chart_data` to `data` property of some series?

Comment: Hi ! Sorry for the waiting time ^^" 
@BarbaraLaird : I can't reproduce the issue in JSFiddle, I'm using sessionStorage to stock and then get my ajax response. But here's the JSFiddle I'm using to test my code : http://jsfiddle.net/rzgsk7e5/14/

Comment: @KamilKulig : I'm not sure to understand your question, did the JSFiddle link above help you ?

Comment: Chart in your jsfiddle shows up and seems to work correctly - it doesn't reproduce the issue. What I meant in my question is that you could make a mistake while composing the series options (JSON). Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/17tcymL0/ Here I  assigned data incorrectly - the chart renders but it has no series and doesn't produce any errors in the console.

Comment: I tried with exactly the same options declaration than in the JSFiddle and it still not working. Actually, only the chart title and the export button are showing up. I add my complete chart generation code, hope it will be useful ^^"

Comment: Ok... Find the problem but not understanding it x) I just delete the "desc" and "value" from the first element of my json and everything works fine now...

Comment: Please provide the content of `new_data` variable.

Comment: Can't provide this var, it's protected ^^" Anyway, it works ^^"